# Define together with the $x$-axis an area.

Tags: definite-integrals, graphing-functions, plane-curves

The curves $y = \sqrt{2x+3}$ and $y = x$ define together with the $x$-axis an area. Determine the exact value of the specific area.

How do you solve?

Comment: If you draw a diagram you'll see that your suposed area is not well defined...Perhaps you meant "with the $\,y$-axis" ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Area you're supposed to find is $\int_{-1.5}^3 \sqrt{2x+3}- \int_0^3{x}$

Comment: This is wrong: there is no interception at $\,x=-1\,$ as $\,\sqrt{2x+3}\,$ is always non-negative.

Comment: @DonAntonio: We're supposed to find the integral from $0$ to $3$. ?

Comment: I don't know, @Inceptio : that's what I'm trying the OP to answer (read my comment below the question). A simple diagram shows the question is, at least, weird, since there is *no* clear area between those curves and the $\,x$-axis . There is though between the curves and the $\,y$-axis ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: It seems more fine now. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes @inceptio, yet the way the question's posed leaves, I believe, room to some doubt...but perhaps it's only me. Just edit your answer since the first integral must have lower limit equal to $\,\color{red}-1.5\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks. Edited.

Comment: I'll upvote your effort. I don't care whether the OP meant this or not. +1